# How do you convert legacy Dojo Toolkit code to AMD?

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm working with ESRI's JavaScript API and they are beginning to switch from Legacy [Dojo Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit) to [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition). Are there any good resources for how to best convert an application from Legacy to AMD?

Answer (score 0):

There is a page on the Dojo site showing how to migrate from the 1.x version to the 2.0 one, if that's what you are looking for?

Here is the link: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/migration-2.0.html

Answer (score 0):

We use Dojo and ESRI's JavaScript API too for our Mapservice and had to deal with the same question like you. We decide to invent new stuff in AMD-Style and switch the older code step by step. It is a bit irritating at the start but you get used to it.

I use for myself the Dojo References and ESRI API Reference:

Dojo: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/index.html#

or

ESRI: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/

which you will know by yourself I think.

Dojo offers you the possibility to change between the older references and the new, which makes the migration easier. It's like learning a known programming language again.
The link above is a good start to get an overview.

And here's a good tutorial for modern Dojo: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/modern_dojo/